# Custom Font weight in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, material-components-android

my designer give me

```
Font(R.font.source_sans_variable_350)
```

which is 350. I am working on fonts through this [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#fonts). To provide **FontWeight** in **FontFamily**. I checked  **FontWeight.Light** and  **FontWeight.Normal** which is **300** and **400** respectively. So is there any solution for **350** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a class with parameterized constructor . You can just use it like this .

```
Font(resId = R.font.montserrat_light, weight = FontWeight(350))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but check this(may be related to this). to your style file

```
<family name="sans-serif">
     <font weight="300" style="normal">sans_light.Light.ttf</font>
     <font weight="350" style="normal">sans_medium.ttf</font>
     <font weight="400" style="normal">sans_normal.ttf</font>
</family>
```